# How to install specific awscli version in conda env (running 3.6) when not found in current channels

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6, conda, aws-cli

I am trying to install a specific version of awscli within my conda environment (running python 3.6). I have tried adding `conda-forge` to my current channels, as suggested in another post.

When I run the command `conda install -p /Users/myname/anaconda3/envs/py36 awscli==1.11.156 -y`

It errors with this message:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - awscli==1.11.156

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

Comment: Have you tried to installing it with `pip install awscli==1.11.156`?

Comment: @PauloScardine looks like that worked! I'd thought I needed to install it via conda. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I've made it into an answer in order to help future stackoverflowers with the same doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [conda miths and misconceptions](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/#Myth-#3:-Conda-and-pip-are-direct-competitors) by Jake VanderPlas:

> If all you are doing is installing Python packages within an isolated environment, conda and pip+virtualenv are mostly interchangeable, modulo some difference in dependency handling and package availability. By isolated environment I mean a conda-env or virtualenv, in which you can install packages without modifying your system Python installation.

You can try to activate your virtual environment and just install it using any of the standard methods. Supposing you have created a conda virtual environment named py36:

```
$ source activate py36
```

Or on Windows

```
> activate py36
```

Then you just use any of the standard install methods, for example:

```
$ pip install awscli==1.11.156

$ easy_install https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/archive/1.11.156.tar.gz
```

The downside is that conda is not managing dependencies for packages installed using pip but in most cases it is OK.